# Copy my addresses in different fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, field

i have in my jsp different addresses, I can choose to copy to my fields. I wanted to know if anyone has sample code in javascript to provide me, thank you.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?87514f7c3e.jpg

Different editable fields . A list of address, when I select an address, I want to automatically informs my fields

Comment: could you elaborate? i dont really understand what you want to do

Comment: Different editable fields . A list of address, when I select an address, I automatically informs my fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's time to learn basic JavaScript/HTML DOM :) Here are some tutorials:

- [W3Schools JavaScript tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)
- [W3Schools HTML DOM tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/)
- [Essential JavaScript - tutorial](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Essential_Javascript_--_A_Javascript_Tutorial)

To start, you need to give HTML elements of interest an ID:

```
<input type="text" id="address">
<input type="text" id="otherAddress">
```

You can grab a specific element using [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementById):

```
var addressElement = document.getElementById('address');
var otherAddressElement = document.getElementById('otherAddress');
```

You can get the value by `value` attribute:

```
var addressValue = addressElement.value;
```

You can set the value by the same attribute:

```
otherAddressElement.value = addressValue;
```